# Name of this shelf support screw with plastic head

Tags: screws, shelving, support

This shelf support is a screw with a semi-circular plastic head. Does it have a name? A name that can be used on Google to find this thing. Or the name given by those who produce it.

Additional info: it's total length is 32 mm and the width of the plastic is 20 mm. The visible part of the screw is 17 mm.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shelf Support Flat With Wood Screw.

http://www.sterlect.com/shelf-support-flat-with-wood-screw-2973042.html

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll find a superlative industry term since they're so often proprietary.

- Shelf support screw
- Threaded shelf support
- Twisty bump
- Screwy knob thing