# Name of this shelf support with plastic head and two nails

Tags: shelving, support, nails

This shelf support is a rectangular plastic head on two unequal nails. What's the name of this thing at the producers? Or the name that can be used on Google to find this thing.

- The size of the head is 18 x 11 x 7 mm
- The length of the nails is 11 and 9 mm

[image: Shelf support with two nails and brown plastic head - on Blue plakene]

Comment: Does this go under the shelf to protect it's resting surface?

Comment: Yes, it's like any shelf pin - under the shelf

Comment: So it's just a double nail-on glide then, right?  Finding this exact one would be difficult.  Have you tried contacting the manufacturer or is it's origin unknown?

Comment: Not sure what glide means in this context. You stick this support to the wardrobe wall by nailing it with a hammer, like any regular nail. Unknown origin, unfortunately, but I should ask at the hardware store though. Good idea..

Comment: The most common style of shelf support/rests are the metal kind.  The wardrobes would come with pre-drilled holes so that you can easily raise/lower your shelves.  It might prove difficult to find this using google alone, but if you know the manufacturer of the wardrobe I would just ask them.  Sometimes for small pieces like this, they won't even bother charging you.

Comment: This looks more like it was designed to be a guide or bumper than a shelf support.  Besides the fact that it wouldn't support any significant weight, shelf supports have to be at precise locations, so they normally go into pre-drilled holes.  I've never seen ones that you hammer in as would be required here.

Comment: @fixer1234 - here in Spain, such shelf supports are not uncommon. They don't use any pre-drilled holes. Here is an example: https://www.flickr.com/photos/152076002@N07/36572085953/in/dateposted-public/ - another one here - using a screw instead of nails - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/123389/name-of-this-shelf-support-screw-with-plastic-head